# How to poll email with hosted solutions? PHP or ASP

Tags: php, .net, email, polling

I have been looking for some time now but i cannot really find a good way to process an emial box using a hosted solution as justhost or asphost . Now my instinct tells me to write a service .. but i cant install it on either hosts.

Is there any other clever way to over come this problem using any thing from PHP to .NET?

Comment: Why don't you do it in a cronjob?

Comment: What seems obvious for you - was a galaxy away from me :) Thx i will have to check that.

Comment: If you don't know how to read IMAP inbox's via PHP, check out this tutorial: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/15/6/1

Comment: Great i see justhost supports cron jobs- i never used this before and it want me to input linux commands. Would i just point to a webpage service every 30 minutes to run it and process my emails? Is reading up on crontab the same as cronjob?

Comment: `0 * * * * http://www.mysite.uk/checkemail.aspx  ` ? does it allow cross domain

Comment: Yes. The program (CLI) used to create Cron Jobs is called `crontab`.

Comment: Can you write an answer so i can accept it- thanks again! you really saved me a while of frustration :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your webserver is running *nix, you should use `crontab` to create a cronjob that'll run automatically at your specified times.

If your server is running any form of Windows, you'll have to use Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Like you said- on asphost i have a schedule button- but i can only do predefined taks.. on justhost i can use the cronjob and run anything i want. :) Fantastic - thanks for getting me out of the dark ages :)